# iPhone 5s slow on wifi

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5s that was bought several months ago. For some reason, it is quite slow on the wifi in my house - noticeably slower than 4g/LTE speed - and has been this way from the beginning. Other devices (Macbook, iPhone 4) do not have this problem when used from the same location. Also, the phone seems to work well on other wifi networks. Are there any ways to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Yes, there are.  However, more information would be helpful:
How are you checking your network speed on the iPhone?  
What is your ISP downlink/uplink speed?  
What spec is your 802.11 router?  
What is the speed you are experiencing? on the iPhone and on your Macbook?  
Can you see what kind of connection your phone is negotiating with your router? This would likely be available on one of the admin screens from your router.  
If the connection is not 802.11n, that's the most likely issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to follow Apple's steps in [troubleshooting generate Wifi issues](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1398).

In addition, try resetting the iPhone's Network Settings by navigating to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings, then restart the iPhone and re-connect to the WiFi network.

Comment: Thanks for the trouble shooting link. What seemed to work was restart phone, hit forget the network in the wi-fi info screen. You need to hit the i to get there. Then reconnect and put in your network password again. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Wi-Fi and forgot the network that I was connected to. I restarted my iPhone 5s and after reboot found the wireless network. I re-entered the password and joined.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely....so easy and I followed the gentleman on "You tube"..
go to settings, general and go to reset and then reset network..Then all you have to do is put your password in for wifi.  As what I understand the problem was on the last update  Good luck

Answer (score -2):

What I found that really helps me is getting the app called battery doctor and it's free of course it works so well when I clean my junks files the iPhone immediately starts working fast